# Почему в mariadb 10.6.11 происходит copy to tmp table при добавлении поля в конец таблицы со значением по умолчанию NULL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Есть две больших таблицы (> 10GB). При добавлении в одну из них поля в конец таблицы происходит copy to tmp table, при добавлении в другую происходит сразу altering table - это видно в phpmyadmin во вкладке состояние, столбец состояние. Почему так происходит? Насколько знаю, в более поздних версиях mysql и mariadb такие запросы должны выполняться без копирования данных во временную таблицу. Обе таблицы innodb. Пример запроса

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD `last_field` VARCHAR(511) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `last_field_now`
```